# Why can't I buy Unicoins?

Tags: discussion, fun, unicoins

I don't want to wait until tomorrow because for my wife's birthday I wanted to buy her Unicoins and today is her birthday.  What is this error, though?  I want Unicoins!
<sub>PS: I'm not really married and I don't have a wife, I just made that up for the sake of story.</sub>

Comment: Mine them... that will show her your dedication!

Comment: So you are married and you are just 13, How old is your wife?

Comment: Which one @user689?

Comment: If I can't buy them with dogecoin they're worthless...

Comment: @user689 In my country, people are married before they're born.

Comment: @TheWobbuffet Your country is Texas?

Comment: @BlueIce No, that's my state.

Comment: -1. Your question is incomprehensible.

Comment: @sawa You must be in a different time zone; this is probably over for you, but there were these things called 'Unicoins' and if you try to buy them, it says 'error, try again tomorrow'.  Please don't downvote what you don't understand...

Comment: @TheWobbuffet I know that. I also saw that message. I don't understand what you are implying that I don't understand. If you say your question is not incomprehensible, then please explain how you can have a wife without getting married.

Comment: @sawa Ok, edited

Comment: +1 for not really being married

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As usual you just didn't listen, did you? Your wife wants a unique Óin. As in, a figurine of Óin, son of Glóin, one of Tolkien's middle earth dwarfs. So go buy her one and thank me later.

How I know? ..... Look, a squirrel!!

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a community level intervention, SO is trying to tell you is that you got it all wrong - Women don't really dig this money thing, they're spiritual souls, they like stuff like love and peace, and naming strange colors with whacky names although they really all look the same.

Don't buy her material stuff like unicoins, or flowers, and definitely not chocolate. Instead, buy her a subscription to the gym, all women accept that as a token of affection. Also - it doesn't have to be on her birthday, try to disregard that date altogether if possible, and pop it at a later date - she'll appreciate the surprise.

Comment: +1 for trying to increase divorce rate in the world! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow is developing Unicorns using Agile methodology, so features will appear as soon as they happen! Hold on tight.